# Text overflowing out of a div in a straight line

Tags: text, overflow

I have a "body" column in my SQL database which is set to 'text' and from here I have unformatted text stored, when I echo this out in a variable in my while loop inside of index.php instead of staying inside of the div it is placed in, it overflows the div, Can someone help me?

This is my while loop code, the CSS is included into the echoed HTML tag.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$id = $row['id'];
$date = $row['date'];
$body = $row['body'];
$postdate = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($date));

echo "Posted on: $postdate";
if(isset($_COOKIE['userlogin']))
{
echo " <a href='edit.php?id=$id' style='float:    right;'>Edit News</a> <a style='float: right;'>[ | ]</a> <a href='delete.php?id=$id' style='float: right;'>Delete News</a>";
}
```

From here is where I am getting the problem:

```
echo "<br />";
echo "<div style='width=800px; border: 1px solid #FFF;'>$body</div>";
echo "<hr width='100%' />";

}
```

It seems that even with the overflow value in place, and the width. That the text still extrudes from it's div tag.

Comment: at a guess, you need to check your CSS. Please post some example code.

Comment: I have added my code to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

well for most browsers you need to specify a width for the div or it will overflow...also set overflow to auto:

```
<div style="width:xpx;overflow:auto>echo text</div>
```

do i understand you correctly?

Comment: Your relatively close, but I do not wish to have to scroll through the div, I just wish the text to stack normally like it would inside of a DIV without the text flowing out of the div.

Comment: well maybe it is because there is no whitespace in the text and therefore the browser won't know where to insert a newline. If that is the case you can use style="word-wrap:break-word"

Comment: oh and with your code above try style="width:800px" instead of style="width=800px"